# How to read .wpd sas dataset in python/pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, sas-wps

Hey I am trying to import .wpd sas dataset in python.
But unable to get the solution.
Can anyone please help me out on this.

I have tried it using below class in python:
import json
import numpy as np
class JSONData:
def **init**(self, filename):
with open(filename) as data_file:self.data = json.load(data_file)

```
def getDatasetCount(self):
    return len(self.data['wpd']['dataSeries'])

def getDatasetByIndex(self, index):
    return self.data['wpd']['dataSeries'][index]

def getDatasetByName(self, name):
    return [x for x in self.data['wpd']['dataSeries'] if x['name'] == name][0]

def getDatasetNames(self):
    return [x['name'] for x in self.data['wpd']['dataSeries']]

def getDatasetValues(self, dataset):
    values = []
    for val in dataset['data']:values.append(val['value'])
    return np.array(values)
```

But no luck.
Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: You can try this approach but WPD is a proprietary data set from a SAS copycat so no idea if the file structure is the same. https://www.anegron.site/2018/11/27/read-sas-datasets-in-python/

Comment: Thanks, but its not working

Comment: Do you think it would be helpful to show what you actually tried and if you received an error? Not working could mean anything from your computer exploded to you missed a period or space.

Comment: FYI - I changed the tags to be WPS as this isn't actually related to SAS at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPS allows you to save a sas7bdat file. I recommend using WPS to create a new file instead of trying to get the WPS file read.

Then `pandas`, a python extension, can read sas sas7bdat files as a dataframe

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sas.html